# Проблема с разделением строки C#

Tags: c#, строки

Имеется программа, которая открывает файл Settings.ini, расшифровывает содержимое, заносит в таблицу данные, и зашифровывает файл обратно.

Работает она по следующему коду:

```
string path1 = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/Settings.ini";
             using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1))
                     {
                      text = Decrypt(sr.ReadToEnd(), "Key");  
                     }
                     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path1, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                     {
                         sw.WriteLine(text);
                     }
                     foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path1)) 
                     {
                         var array = line.Split('|');
                         dataGridView1.Rows.Add(array);
                     }
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1))
                     {
                         text = Encrypt(sr.ReadToEnd(), ppap);
                     }
                     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path1, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                     {
                         sw.WriteLine(text);
                     }
```

Т.е программа открывает содержимое файла, расшифровывает его, получает готовый текст, в котором линии, в этих линиях слова через разделитель
Например:

```
Слово1|Слово2|Слово3|
Слово4|Слово5|Слово6|
```

Я захотел упростить код, и сделать так, чтобы программа сразу расшифровывала файл (Не меняя ресурсы файла Settings.ini), и получала строки, которые позже загружала в dataGridView. Мучался час с проблемой, ничего не получалось. Надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Вот набросок кода (Неправильного), который я смог написать.

Работает он конечно же некорректно

```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1))
            {
                var MyList = Decrypt(sr.ReadToEnd(), "key").ToList();
                foreach (var line in MyList) 
                {
                    var array = line.ToString().Split('|'); //Выводит в таблицу строки через символ (Вот в чем некорректность данного кода)
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(array);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Может, `var MyList = Decrypt(sr.ReadToEnd(), "key").Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Split('|'))`, а затем `foreach (var array in MyList) { dataGridView1.Rows.Add(array);  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = Decrypt(File.ReadAllText(path1));
```

Можно передавать `text` в `StringReader` - из него читаем построчно так же, как из `StreamReader`а:

```
using (var sr = new StringReader(text))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        dgv.Rows.Add(line.Split('|'));
}
```

Жаль, у стрингридера нет такого удобного метода, как `File.ReadLines`.

Другой способ:

```
var lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    dgv.Rows.Add(line.Split('|'));
}
```